# Use CamanJS on webworker

Tags: javascript, image-processing, asynchronous, parallel-processing, camanjs

Can I use caman.js library for processing image on webworker? As far as is I known, WebWorker cant run code which contain operation with document. How I can run such of code which have working with document on worker?

Answer (score 0):

Within the worker, it's possible to import external scripts with `importScripts()`